# Nested if-else statements are giving me problems

Tags: c

The code I wrote is supposed to count the amount of a's, c's, t's, and g's in a char pointer list. Then if the entered char is not an a, c, t, or g, then it is supposed to add the invalid letter into the char list invalidBase. Instead when I enter the data agtcpoop it prints out Invalid Base: but the chars are not there, when it is supposed to print out poop. Please help! Here is the code:

```
void countBase(char *p)
{
   int aCount = 0, cCount = 0, tCount = 0, gCount = 0;
   char invalidBase[100];
   int i, j=0;
   while(*p != '\0')
{
  if(*p == 'A' || *p == 'a')
  {
     aCount++;
  }
  else if(*p == 'C' || *p == 'c')
  {
     cCount++;
  }
  else if(*p == 'T' || *p == 't')
  {
     tCount++;
  }
  else if(*p == 'G' || *p == 'g')
  {
     gCount++;
  }
  else
  {
     invalidBase[j] = *p;
  }
  j++;
  p++;
}

for(i = 0; invalidBase[i] != '\0'; i++)
{
   printf("Invalid Base: %c\n", invalidBase[i]);
}

printf(" A: %i\n C: %i\n T: %i\n G: %i\n", aCount, cCount, tCount, gCount);
}
```

Comment: My guess right now after thinking more about it, is that I need to dereference invalidBase in the else statement? By using a pointer? Such as have it in the else statement be *invalidBase = *p; then increment invalidBase instead of j++. Is this close? **I THINK THIS IS WAY OFF AFTER GETTING MIKECATS REPLY!**

Comment: No, you cannot increment `invalidBase` because it is an array and ih wil be automatic converted ti a pointer, which id not a lvalue, when it is used in expressions except for operands of `sizeof` or unary `&` operator.

Comment: You may want to use `switch` statement instead of these many `if-else` statements.

Comment: @MikeCAT I tried, but I seemed to have problems using switch statements for the pointer. I looked it up online and was unable to find out how to do it. Maybe I just did some silly mistake, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: I added a code using `switch` statement to my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Yoy invoked *undefined behavior* by using values of uninitialized variables having automatic storage duration, which is indeterminate.

To improve:

- Increment the counter `j` only if a data is stored to `invalidBase`.
- Use `j` to determine the length to print.

Improved code:

```
void countBase(char *p)
{
   int aCount = 0, cCount = 0, tCount = 0, gCount = 0;
   char invalidBase[100];
   int i, j=0;
   while(*p != '\0')
   {
      if(*p == 'A' || *p == 'a')
      {
         aCount++;
      }
      else if(*p == 'C' || *p == 'c')
      {
         cCount++;
      }
      else if(*p == 'T' || *p == 't')
      {
         tCount++;
      }
      else if(*p == 'G' || *p == 'g')
      {
         gCount++;
      }
      else
      {
         if(j < (int)(sizeof(invalidBase) / sizeof(*invalidBase))) /* avoid buffer overrun */
         {
            invalidBase[j] = *p;
            j++;
         }
      }
      p++;
   }

   for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
   {
      printf("Invalid Base: %c\n", invalidBase[i]);
   }

   printf(" A: %i\n C: %i\n T: %i\n G: %i\n", aCount, cCount, tCount, gCount);
}
```

Note that you can use `switch` statement instead of these many `if-else` statements.

```
void countBase(char *p)
{
   int aCount = 0, cCount = 0, tCount = 0, gCount = 0;
   char invalidBase[100];
   int i, j=0;
   while(*p != '\0')
   {
      switch(*p)
      {
      case 'A':
      case 'a':
         aCount++;
         break;
      case 'C':
      case 'c':
         cCount++;
         break;
      case 'T':
      case 't':
         tCount++;
         break;
      case 'G':
      case 'g':
         gCount++;
         break;
      default:
         if(j < (int)(sizeof(invalidBase) / sizeof(*invalidBase))) /* avoid buffer overrun */
         {
            invalidBase[j] = *p;
            j++;
         }
         break;
      }
      p++;
   }

   for(i = 0; i < j; i++)
   {
      printf("Invalid Base: %c\n", invalidBase[i]);
   }

   printf(" A: %i\n C: %i\n T: %i\n G: %i\n", aCount, cCount, tCount, gCount);
}
```

Comment: god I love you <3. Such a dumb error. Thank you....  I looked at this forever. Was doing so much research into nested if loops thinking I did something wrong. Thank you <3

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void countBase(char *p) {
    int aCount = 0, cCount = 0, tCount = 0, gCount = 0;
    char invalidBase[100];
    int i, j=0;
    while(*p != '\0') {
        if(tolower(*p) == 'a') {
            aCount++;
        }
        else if(tolower(*p) == 'c') {
            cCount++;
        }
        else if(tolower(*p) == 't') {
            tCount++;
        }
        else if(tolower(*p) == 'g') {
            gCount++;
        }
        else {
            // This is the correct place to increment j.
            invalidBase[j++] = *p;
        }

        // The following line is wrong. You can only increment j if an invalid
        // base was found and inserted on the array.
        // j++;
        p++;
    }

    // Your code lacked the "end of string" delimitation.
    invalidBase[j] = '\0';

    for(i = 0; invalidBase[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        printf("Invalid Base: %c\n", invalidBase[i]);
    }

    printf(" A: %i\n C: %i\n T: %i\n G: %i\n", aCount, cCount, tCount, gCount);
}

int main(){
    printf("Testing '%s'\n", "agtcpoop");
    countBase("agtcpoop");
    puts("***********************************");
    printf("Testing '%s'\n", "a");
    countBase("a");
    puts("***********************************");
    printf("Testing '%s'\n", "");
    countBase("");
    puts("***********************************");
    printf("Testing '%s'\n", "p");
    countBase("p");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Ah! I like this! Thank you very much! Much cleaner. Also, I thought it added the \0 automatically? I never added it to the pointer!?

Comment: This usage of `tolower()` may invoke *undefined behavior* for passing out-of-range value. Casting `*p` to `unsigned char` before passing it is good to prevent it.